# API Error for BluetoothSerialPort.getSerialPortInfo()

Tags: blackberry, bluetooth, serial-port

I am using `BluetoothSerialPort.getSerialPortInfo()` for extracting devices which are paired during Bluetooth connection.

But this works some times and does not other times it gives `null` other times ...

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer from this link

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Bluetooth-serial-Port-example/td-p/22101

> Issue solved by accident:
>
> Before you paired the two devices,
>
> 1) you need to open the "Bluetooth sample" and select "listen for
>   connections". you can either use one or both devices for listening(in
>   this case you will have bi-direction connection initilization, which
>   is cool~).
>
> 2)then let the "Bluetooth sample" APPLICATION run at the background,
>   open the regular Set up Blue tooth options, one listen and the other
>   search for connection. then pair the two devices.
>
> 3)now, you could have the bluetooth option at the "Bluetooth sample"
>   quit and re-start the applications
>
> 4)start bluetooth data transfer.